# How do I make turtles search for patches with set conditions in a set radius

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to code a turtle search function where:

if sociability >= 0.5 and local patch density < target density

then search in-radius Moves_per_tick for a patch with a difference between density and target density less than the difference between current density and target density.

If one exists then move to that patch.
If none exist then make a random movement of length moves_per_tick

But I'm not familiar enough with the NetLogo language yet to make this happen. I've looked at several similar questions but none of them got me close enough to my goal.

I'm currently working off this code, which is broken in many ways:

```
to start_search_personality
  let LD density
  let AT (Target_density * sociability)
  let C_D (AT - LD)

  if sociability >= 0.5 
  [
     ifelse C_D >= 0
      [
         let P any? one-of patches with (patches in-radius moves_per_tick with [density] > LD)
         if [density] of P > LD 
         [face p move-to p]]  
      [move-to patch-here]
  ]
```

Density is owned by patches and defined as the count of turtles in the patch.
Turtles own sociability, which is a value between 0 and 1.
Target density is input from elsewhere, and is an integer.

Not asking anyone to debug this code, but at least let me know if I'm on the right track or suggest where I should be looking. Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying a patch is calling this function? Since density is a patch-variable? If so, how can a patch move? Seems your mixing the definitions of the patch's density and the number of turtles on the patch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my best attempt at trying to understand the logic.

```
to start_search_personality
  let density-here count turtles-here

  if sociability >= 0.5 and density-here < target-density
  [
     let p patches in-radius moves_per_tick
     ifelse any? p with [target-density < abs (density - target-density)] 
     [move-to one-of p with  [target-density < abs (density - target-density)]]
     [ ;;move in a random direction of length moves per tick
       set heading (random 360)
       fd moves_per_tick 
     ]     
  ]
```

Comment: Thanks that got me a lot closer to the ultimate goal, and answers the above question well. This function is invoked by move, which is in go (a forever function), but it only works once. How do I get it to re-run this search every tick until local density >= the target density? I've messed around with loops a bit but every time I do I end up in an infinite series that freezes the model...

Comment: I don't think a function called once is forever...Are you sure your go button has the forever selected?

Comment: yes, could the problem be that the search function is called second hand? In other words, is it a problem that I invoke this function with Move, which is invoked with Go?

Comment: If you selected go to be called forever and inside your go function you have a move function which calls this function, this function should also be called every time unit. Are you sure this function isn't being called? i.e. it reaches the function, but the movement never occurs since sociability is less than 5, for example. Aside, you can either post more code here or put print statements to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: I'm simplifying the main code down now but it looks like the issue at this point is that I'm invoking the function with a progression of logic statements and for whatever reason the turtles aren't getting that far even though the conditions are satisfied. I'll update the code for this question once I get it working, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Using the comments above I now have a functional code. If you're re-purposing it for yourself, I'd recommend removing the color changes (which I just used to test that each function was called). Target_density is fixed at the beginning of the run, turtles own s (which is fixed between 0 and 1), patches own density (which is updated on each tick and defined as the count of turtles in the patch). The last hurdle will be to establish a ranking system as the this code is sensitive to high target_densities

```
to check_personality
  move-to patch-here
  let N max-one-of neighbors [density]
   let ND max [density] of neighbors 
   let LD [density] of patch-here
   let AT (Target_density * s)
   let p patches in-radius moves_per_tick_baseline
   let diff_1 (AT - LD) < (AT - ND)
   let diff_2 (AT - LD) > (AT - ND)
   let diff_3 (AT - LD) = (AT - ND)

 ifelse s > 0.5

 [if LD < AT[ 

if diff_1 [ set color white
  ifelse density >= (0.90 * AT)
    [move-to patch-here]
    [ifelse any? p with [density > LD]
      [move-to one-of p with [density > LD]]
      [face N forward moves_per_tick_baseline]
    ]
   ] 

if diff_2[ set color gray
  move-to N
         ]

if diff_3
 [if ND < LD 
     [
     set color black 
     ifelse any? p with [density >= LD]
     [move-to one-of p with [density >= LD]]
     [face N forward moves_per_tick_baseline]
     ]

  if ND > LD 
     [move-to patch-here face N move-to N]]
  if ND = LD 
     [ifelse ND = 0 
       [set heading (random 360) forward moves_per_tick_baseline]
       [set heading (random 360) forward moves_per_tick_baseline]
     ]
 ]


 if LD >= AT [set color yellow set size 10]]
```